# Angular6 Get method response "_isScalar":false,"source"

Tags: angular

I am trying to show the json data on the html page. The data on the server shows me json data but when i try to show it on page it gives me this data

> {"_isScalar":false,"source":{"_isScalar":false,"source":{"_isScalar":false,"source":{"_isScalar":true,"value":{"url":"https://feeds.citibikenyc.com/stations/stations.json","body":null,"reportProgress":false,"withCredentials":false,"responseType":"json","method":"GET","headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"params":{"updates":null,"cloneFrom":null,"encoder":{},"map":null},"urlWithParams":"https://feeds.citibikenyc.com/stations/stations.json"},"scheduler":null},"operator":{"concurrent":1}},"operator":{}},"operator":{}}

my code for getting the data is

```
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class GetdataService {
posts : any;
readonly ROOT_URL ="https://feeds.citibikenyc.com/stations/stations.json";
constructor(private http: HttpClient ) { }

getPosts()
{

this.posts = this.http.get(this.ROOT_URL );

return JSON.stringify(this.posts);
}


}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`this.http.get()` doesn't return data but rather an observable, that you have to subscribe to:

```
getPosts() {
  this.http.get(this.ROOT_URL)
    .subscribe((data) => {
        //DO STUFF HERE
    });
}
```

[Readmore](https://angular.io/guide/http)

Secondly, while it shouldn't be needed to decode JSON after you fix the observable-stuff, you decode json with `JSON.parse()` not `JSON.stringify`. `stringify` converts the object into string (the exact opposite of what you wanted).