# Angular HttpClient Module - Trying to get data from a URL

Tags: angular, typescript, http, get, httpclient

I am creating a project for my own use, using Angular.

I am trying to store the response from this [url](https://www.fixtureslive.com/apiv3/statzone_comp.ashx?divid=60166&passKey=362483838&displayMode=js&hostname=wessexbasketball.co.uk) as a string. It's the string from the "currentPage.content" variable.

I am trying to use the HttpClient Module, but it is not the response I wanted. Instead, I get the following:

```
{ _isScalar: false, source: {…}, operator: {…} }
```

Can anybody please help me get the correct response? It would be greatly appreciated.

Alternatively, this [url](https://www.fixtureslive.com/apiv3/statzone_comp.ashx?divid=60166&passKey=362483838&displayMode=json&hostname=wessexbasketball.co.uk) also has the data I need. The goal here would be to store this content as a string value.

Thanks.

Comment: would be nice to see you code could you add it for me?

Comment: Please, read the documentation. The http guide is very clear and well written. You absolutely need to read documentation to learn hos to use things. https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: this could reinforce the explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52106855/angular6-get-method-response-isscalarfalse-source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're displaying the Observable returned by the HttpClient `get` call. In order to get the data from your Observable, you need to subscribe to it.

In your service

```js
getContent(): Observable<any> {
    const url = "api/url/goes/here";
    return this.http.get(url);
}
```

Then in your component, where you want to call the API, call `getContent` and subscribe to the Observable

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.getContent().subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```